# construct tensorflow bijectors Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, tensorflow-probability

I am new to use tensorflow. And I want to construct a bijector with the following properties: It takes a n dimensional probability distribution p(x1, x2, ..., xn), and it only transforms two certain dimensions i and j, such that xi' = xi, xj' = xj*exp(s(xi)) + t(xj), where s and t are two functions realized using neural networks. It outputs p(x1, x2, ..., xi', .., xj', .., xn). 
I have a basic code looks like below:

```
  def net(x, out_size, block_w_id, block_d_id, layer_id):
    x = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, 256, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, scope='x1_block_w_{}_block_d_{}_layer_{}'.format(block_w_id, \
                                                                                                                       block_d_id,\
                                                                                                                       layer_id))
    x = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, 256, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, scope='x2_block_w_{}_block_d_{}_layer_{}'.format(block_w_id,\
                                                                                                                       block_d_id,\
                                                                                                                       layer_id))
    y = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, out_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, scope='y_block_w_{}_block_d_{}_layer_{}'.format(block_w_id,\
                                                                                                                           block_d_id,\
                                                                                                                           layer_id))
#     return layers.stack(x, layers.fully_connected(reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE), [512, 512, out_size])
    return y
```

---

```
class NVPCoupling(tfb.Bijector):
    """NVP affine coupling layer for 2D units.
    """
    def __init__(self, input_idx1, input_idx2, block_w_id = 0, block_d_id = 0, layer_id = 0, validate_args = False\
                 , name="NVPCoupling"):
        """
        NVPCoupling only manipulate two inputs with idx1 & idx2.
        """
        super(NVPCoupling, self).__init__(\
                                         event_ndims = 1, validate_args = validate_args, name = name)
        self.idx1 = input_idx1
        self.idx2 = input_idx2
        self.block_w_id = block_w_id
        self.block_d_id = block_d_id
        self.layer_id = layer_id
        # create variables
        tmp = tf.placeholder(dtype=DTYPE, shape = [1, 1])
        self.s(tmp) 
        self.t(tmp)

    def s(self, xd):
        with tf.variable_scope('s_block_w_id_{}_block_d_id_{}_layer_{}'.format(self.block_w_id,\
                                                                              self.block_d_id,\
                                                                              self.layer_id),\
                              reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            return net(xd, 1, self.block_w_id, self.block_d_id, self.layer_id)
    def t(self, xd):
        with tf.variable_scope('t_block_w_id_{}_block_d_id_{}_layer_{}'.format(self.block_w_id,\
                                                                              self.block_d_id,\
                                                                              self.layer_id),\
                              reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            return net(xd, 1, self.block_w_id, self.block_d_id, self.layer_id)
    def _forward(self, x):
        x_left, x_right = x[:, self.idx1:(self.idx1 + 1)], x[:, self.idx2:(self.idx2 + 1)]
        y_right = x_right * tf.exp(self.s(x_left)) + self.t(x_left)

        output_tensor = tf.concat([ x[:,0:self.idx1], x_left, x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]\
                                   , y_right, x[:, (self.idx2+1):]], axis = 1)
        return output_tensor
    def _inverse(self, y):
        y_left, y_right = y[:, self.idx1:(self.idx1 + 1)], y[:, self.idx2:(self.idx2 + 1)]
        x_right = (y_right - self.t(y_left)) * tf.exp(-self.s(y_left))
        output_tensor = tf.concat([ y[:, 0:self.idx1], y_left, y[:, self.idx1+1 : self.idx2]\
                                  , x_right, y[:, (self.idx2+1):]], axis = 1)
        return output_tensor
    def _forward_log_det_jacobian(self, x):
        event_dims = self._event_dims_tensor(x)
        x_left = x[:, self.idx1:(self.idx1+1)]
        return tf.reduce_sum(self.s(x_left), axis=event_dims)
```

---

But it didn't work as I think it is. When I use the class, it pops up an error:

```
base_dist = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=tf.zeros([2], DTYPE))
num_bijectors = 4
bijectors = []
bijectors.append(NVPCoupling(input_idx1=0, input_idx2=1, \
                             block_w_id=0, block_d_id=0, layer_id=0))
bijectors.append(NVPCoupling(input_idx1=1, input_idx2=0, \
                             block_w_id=0, block_d_id=0, layer_id=1))
bijectors.append(NVPCoupling(input_idx1=0, input_idx2=1, \
                             block_w_id=0, block_d_id=0, layer_id=2))
bijectors.append(NVPCoupling(input_idx1=0, input_idx2=1, \
                             block_w_id=0, block_d_id=0, layer_id=3))
flow_bijector = tfb.Chain(list(reversed(bijectors)))
dist = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    distribution=base_dist,
    bijector=flow_bijector)
dist.sample(1000)
```

---

with error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-04da05d30f8d> in <module>()
----> 1 dist.sample(1000)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/distribution.pyc in sample(self, sample_shape, seed, name)
    708       samples: a `Tensor` with prepended dimensions `sample_shape`.
    709     """
--> 710     return self._call_sample_n(sample_shape, seed, name)
    711 
    712   def _log_prob(self, value):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/transformed_distribution.pyc in _call_sample_n(self, sample_shape, seed, name, **kwargs)
    412       # returned result.
    413       y = self.bijector.forward(x, **kwargs)
--> 414       y = self._set_sample_static_shape(y, sample_shape)
    415 
    416       return y

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/distribution.pyc in _set_sample_static_shape(self, x, sample_shape)
   1220       shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(
   1221           [None]*(ndims - event_ndims)).concatenate(self.event_shape)
-> 1222       x.set_shape(x.get_shape().merge_with(shape))
   1223 
   1224     # Infer batch shape.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.pyc in merge_with(self, other)
    671         return TensorShape(new_dims)
    672       except ValueError:
--> 673         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))
    674 
    675   def concatenate(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (1000, 4) and (?, 2) are not compatible
```

---

Really hope some experts could help me understanding where I did wrong and how to fix that. Many Thanks!
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is here (reformatted slightly for clarity):

```
output_tensor = tf.concat([
    x[:,0:self.idx1],
    x_left,
    x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2],
    y_right,
    x[:, (self.idx2+1):]
], axis = 1)
```

This assumes `idx2 > idx1` which is not true in the case where you give `idx1=1` and `idx2=0`. This causes you to concat more things than you meant to giving the 2nd dim of 4 instead of 2.

I printed shapes in `_forward` thus:

```
print("self.idx1: %s" % self.idx1)
print("self.idx2: %s" % self.idx2)
print("x[:,0:self.idx1]: %s" % x[:,0:self.idx1].shape)
print("x_left: %s" % x_left.shape)
print("x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]: %s" %
      x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2].shape)
print("x_right.shape: %s" % x_right.shape)
print("y_right: %s" % y_right.shape)
print("x[:, (self.idx2+1):]: %s" % x[:, (self.idx2+1):].shape)
print("output_tensor.shape: %s" % output_tensor.shape)
```

And got this output:

```
self.idx1: 0
self.idx2: 1
x[:,0:self.idx1]: (1000, 0)
x_left: (1000, 1)
x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]: (1000, 0)
x_right.shape: (1000, 1)
y_right: (1000, 1)
x[:, (self.idx2+1):]: (1000, 0)
output_tensor.shape: (1000, 2)

self.idx1: 1
self.idx2: 0
x[:,0:self.idx1]: (1000, 1)
x_left: (1000, 1)
x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]: (1000, 0)
x_right.shape: (1000, 1)
y_right: (1000, 1)
x[:, (self.idx2+1):]: (1000, 1)
output_tensor.shape: (1000, 4)

self.idx1: 0
self.idx2: 1
x[:,0:self.idx1]: (1000, 0)
x_left: (1000, 1)
x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]: (1000, 0)
x_right.shape: (1000, 1)
y_right: (1000, 1)
x[:, (self.idx2+1):]: (1000, 2)
output_tensor.shape: (1000, 4)

self.idx1: 0
self.idx2: 1
x[:,0:self.idx1]: (1000, 0)
x_left: (1000, 1)
x[:, self.idx1+1:self.idx2]: (1000, 0)
x_right.shape: (1000, 1)
y_right: (1000, 1)
x[:, (self.idx2+1):]: (1000, 2)
output_tensor.shape: (1000, 4)
```

I think you'll need to think a little more carefully about re-assembling the concat'ed pieces in this block, when idx1 > idx2.

Hope this gets you back on track!